# Domestic LAN network

Tags: windows, windows-vista

O.S Vista 64 Home Premium.

I'd like to uninstall the Home Network I created previously. I experimented several actions which didn't work at all. What's to be done please ?.

Cordially,

Pierre LEROY

Comment: Hi Pierre, and welcome to Super User (and the rest of the SOFU family)! Could you please clarify your question a bit? Do you want to disable and remove your network adapter, or reset it's settings, or something else entirely?

Comment: yank the wire out.  (kidding. don't do that. unplug it *gently*.)

Answer (score 1):

If we're not talking about the wiring then you don't *install* a Home network, you just create one. And to leave it, just abandon it.

Go to My Computer, Properties, Adv System setting, Computer name. set another Network ID.